# MP4 / H.264 Content Played On Browser That Doesn't Have Native HTML5 or Flash Support For It

Tags: html, youtube, media, mp4, h.264

I am working on an addon for a sandbox game, Garry's Mod, that plays YouTube videos and other media content in-game. The addon has been around for quite some time, known as PlayX, but things are just now majorly switching over to HTML5, which have helped to improve, but also break the player addon. The major limitation here is that the HTML framework in-game is Awesomium, or Chrome 18. Thus, only Webm and a few other formats are supported by the native HTML5 player. I am using JWPlayer as the host player, playing in HTML5. All standard YouTube videos play perfectly fine using Webm, and other file formats work as well. However, when trying to view MP4 / H.264 content or YouTube live streams, of which most seem to be encoded in MP4, it will simply not play due to it not being supported natively by Chrome 18. The workaround for this is to have players download NPAPI flash and install it, so the player will fall back to Flashplayer. (The in-game browser requires NPAPI flash to be installed by the user for Flash to work, since it does not have it baked in). This however is very convoluted and causes major frustration for players. **My main question here is, is there any way to natively play MP4 / h.264 streams in a browser that does not support it without having to have clients download Flash?** (I know, really dumb question on the surface). Is there any way to force it to play in a different codec (YouTube live streams), or is it locked to that because that is what it is streaming as? Or is there some sort of other player that can accept the MP4 stream and play it in another format real-time? **Basically, I want to avoid users having to install NPAPI flash on their computers just to be able to watch MP4 / H.264 content, because as easy as it sounds, it is highly inconvenient for Garry's Mod players.**

Just for context, a lot of us in the Garry's Mod Community have begged the Garry's Mod developers to update Awesomium / Chrome 18 to a newer version or replace it because it is so ridiculously outdated, but they don't seem to have any plans to do that for a long time, thus, we are stuck.

Any help / suggestions on this would be very much appreciated, I have done hours / days of research with little findings.

Thank you so much,

Adam

Comment: This question seems to me as being equivalent to "Is there any way to have a bath inside a shower without requiring users to install a bathtub?"

Comment: Yeah, I know it sounds like that! But being that there is a workaround to the issue by having Flash be a fallback player, I was just wondering if anyone know of another method of playing the content using another format or player. If MP4 was 100% not compatible, I would not be asking this question, but where there is one solution, Flash, I was just wondering if there might be more that could be purely host side, not having clients have to install something. Does flash offer anything of the sort?

Comment: @Adam759 Flash Plugin comes with it's own built-in MPEG decoder (mp4, h264, aac, mp3, etc). Youtube Live uses DASH for `http` streaming format. Some other systems use `rtmp` so maybe even Youtube supports that too. Find a way to play DASH streams in a video tag then test with your Youtube links.